# Offset Java Path2D

Tags: java, offset, intersection, self

[image: issue][image: coding][image: expected result]

I create a Path2D path (yellow line). With my program I create the path step by step. Every second I add a  new point to the path and with left and right key I can move the path to the left or right. With AffineTransform I rotate the path depending on the degrees and with piccolo2D API I roate the panel that the orange arrow is always in the middle of the screen and points to north.

Now I want to draw depending on the original path a defined number of paths which are shown right (and later left too) to the original path with an defined offset of e.g. 20 pixel. The offset should be the same for all points. E.g. on each point 20 pixel.

The problem now is that if I drive to the left everything is fine because I drive an outer curve. If I drive to the right (inner curve) I get self intersection of the path. I want to have the offset paths similar to the original path.

I´m not sure how can I solve this issue. I want to have a path without self intersection.

Has anybody an idea how I can solve this issue?

Code of moveTo method:

` public static GeoPosition movePoint(GeoPosition _gp, double distanceInMetres, double bearing) {

```
    GeoPosition gp = _gp;

    try
    {

    double latitude = _gp.getLatitude();
    double longitude = _gp.getLongitude();

    double brngRad = Math.toRadians(bearing);
    double latRad = Math.toRadians(latitude);
    double lonRad = Math.toRadians(longitude);
    int earthRadiusInMetres = 6371000;
    double distFrac = distanceInMetres / earthRadiusInMetres;

    double latitudeResult = Math.asin(Math.sin(latRad) * Math.cos(distFrac) + Math.cos(latRad) * Math.sin(distFrac) * Math.cos(brngRad));
    double a = Math.atan2(Math.sin(brngRad) * Math.sin(distFrac) * Math.cos(latRad), Math.cos(distFrac) - Math.sin(latRad) * Math.sin(latitudeResult));
    double longitudeResult = (lonRad + a + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;


    gp = new GeoPosition(Math.toDegrees(latitudeResult),Math.toDegrees(longitudeResult));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return gp;
}
```

`

Thank you.

Comment: can please you share some code?

Comment: Its difficult to share some code because I have thousends of lines of code. But for better understanding. I have GPS coordinates which I convert to Point2D. Than I add this points to the Path2D.  What I do is to create the path by adding points with once moveTo and than lineTo to the path. The offset points I create with the following method:

Comment: for coding please see picture above

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code as text and a picture of the curve you expect?

Comment: With this method I can move the GPS coordinate to a defined offset e.g. 15 meters and a defined bearing e.g. 60 degrees. This new GPS coordinate I can convert to Point2D and add it to the Path2D path. But if I move the coordinates of the original path 15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135 meters I get self intersections if I use the original bearing. The bearing is set for each point of the PATH2D.

Comment: @Joni Please see the screenshot 3 for the expeced result. How can I add the code as text?

Comment: Important is that the offset lines should have the same offset e.g. 15 meters within all the points of the path